# Subprocess passes information to exe

Tags: python, c++, subprocess, direct3d

I used the subprocess library in python to control the exe file to implement the interaction between python and the 3D model created by Direct3D. I had been successful before, but yesterday I found that he had no response.
below was my code of python.

```
import subprocess
from struct import *

proc = subprocess.Popen("C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/金字塔/Debug/Pyramid.exe",
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    encoding='utf-8')

state = "run"
while state == "run":
    input = "OK"

    if input == "quit":
        state = "terminate" # any string other than "run" will do

    #input = pack()
    proc.stdin.write(input+"\n")
    proc.stdin.flush()
    cppMessage = proc.stdout.readline().rstrip("\n")
    print("cppreturn message ->" + cppMessage + " written by python \n")
```

The following is part of my d3d code in C++.

```
bool Display(float timeDelta)
{
    if (Device)
    {
        //....I I left out the irrelevant part in Display
        std::cin >> python_message;
        //rolation 
        if (python_message == "OK")
        {
            //std::cout << python_message;
            static float y = 0.0f;
            y += timeDelta * 3.0f;
            if (y >= 6.28f)
                y = 0.0f;
            D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matWorld, y);
            Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);
        }
        else if (python_message == "STOP")
        {
            //std::cout << python_message;
            static float y = 0.0f;
            D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matWorld, y);
            Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matWorld);
        }


        Device->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 4);

        Device->EndScene();
        Device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    }
    return true;
}
```

in my main function,i loop the Display function:

```
d3d::EnterMsgLoop(Display);
```

Comment: The loop in the Python code doesn't make much sense. It always sets `input = "OK"`, so the `while` loop will never iterate more than one time — although it may "hang" waiting for the `readline()` to return.

Comment: But after I actually ran it, the exe file didn't respond at all as if it had received the message even always `input = "OK" `